# How do get optional parameter value using javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, parameters

I have following url

http://MySite.com/MyGame/Play/1

Now i wanted to get id **1** (e.g. 1 which is after play) of url using javascript or jquery.

I am using MVC 4.0 C# application.

Comment: Is it possible to do without string operation?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, it will be:

```
var parts = document.location.href.split("/");
var id = parts[parts.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = document.URL.split('/');
```

Then you can do either one of these:

```
var id = url.pop();
```

or

```
var id = url[url.lengh-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adeel and Jeff's solutions will fail if there is no id - like in my case. So i extended it a little bit for my usage. GetIdIfExists function will return the id if there is one. Else, it will return null.

EDIT: Assuming id is always numeric.

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function GetIdIfExists() {
    var parts = document.location.href.split("/");
    var id = parts[parts.length - 1];

    if (isNumeric(id)) {
        return parseInt(id);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
//url = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761950/how-do-get-optional-parameter-value-using-javascript-in-mvc
> GetIdIfExists()
< null

//url = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761950/how-do-get-optional-parameter-value-using-javascript-in-mvc/0
> GetIdIfExists()
< 0
```